# Call Swift function with completion handler in objective c

Tags: objective-c, swift, asynchronous, callback

I am trying to call a Swift function that contains a completion handler in an objective C class, but I am not sure how to implement it.

This is my Swift Code

```
@objc class textToSpeech:NSObject{

func toSpeech(word: NSString, sucess:()->Void) -> NSURL {
    let tempDirectory = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true)
    let tempFile = tempDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent((word as String) + ".wav")

    let tts = TextToSpeech(username: "xxxxxx", password: "xxxxxx")
    tts.synthesize(word as String,
               voice: SynthesisVoice.GB_Kate,
               audioFormat: AudioFormat.WAV,
               failure: { error in
                print("error was generated \(error)")
}) { data in

        data.writeToURL(tempFile, atomically: true)
        print("createdURL")
        print(tempFile)
        sucess();

}

return tempFile
}
```

How would I write the function call in objective c.  I have already completed setting up the project so that I can call swift functions from objective c.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example you have this code:

```
@objc class PDTextToSpeech: NSObject{
  func toSpeech(word: NSString, success: () -> Void) -> NSURL {
    // ...
    return NSURL()
  }
}
```

So you could easily bridge you Swift code in obj-c with `#import "<ModuleName>-Swift.h"`
 where  you project name.

Then you can call:

```
[[PDTextToSpeech new] toSpeech:@"String" success:^{
    NSLog(@"Success");
}];
```

I was using `PDTextToSpeech` as class name, because it's preferable to call classes in obj-c with uniq prefix. If you project called `TestProject` - you can use `TP` prefix.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it should look like this:

```
textToSpeech* text = [[textToSpeech alloc] init];

[text word:@"some text" sucess:^{
    NSLog(@"success");
}];
```